# Vim: Create custom command that takes a movement

Tags: vim

I often transform lines of texts to arrays. For example, this:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

Becomes:

```
[
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
]
```

I can make a map that changes one of the lines (e.g. `Monday` to `'Monday',`) like so:

`:nnoremap gsa ^i'<Esc>A,`

What I'd like to do is have that command take a movement or a text object so that I can execute it like `gsaip` or `gsip3j`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`'operatorfunc'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'operatorfunc') with [`g@`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#g@)  to have a map with a
motion.  The help  gives  a  full explanation  and  example under  the
[`:map-operator`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-operator) topic. Basically you set the function you want to
call in your map and use `g@`. Vim  will wait to a motion and then set
the marks `'[` and `']` and call your function.

Inside your  function you can  go creative, here  I just made  a quick
example of how you could apply this principle to what you need.

```
:nnoremap <silent> gsa :set opfunc=TransformToArray<cr>g@

function! TransformToArray(type)
  if a:type == 'line'
    let s=line("'[") " saving beginning mark
    ']s/\(\s*\).*\zs/\r\1]
    exec s ",']-1s/\\s*\\zs.*/  '&',"
    exec s 's/\(\s*\)\zs\ze  /[\r\1'
  elseif a:type == 'char'
    " ...
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Why not changing `"Go\<bs>]"` to `'Go]'` ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス for me it is needed because of the indentation settings. Since the former line is indented by 2, I remove it with bs before inserting the closing brace. This is just a quick solution, needs more thought to improve :)

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I changed it, seems more compact and less redundant now.

Comment: No need for `if a:type == 'line'` as you are using it in normal-mode

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス True, but my intention was just to demonstrate that you can detect if it was called on lines or char-wise. In case it is the latter maybe something different is wanted. Thanks for the remark! Feel free to edit it out if you want. I'm indifferent regarding that.

Comment: No it's ok ! That still depending on OP but using the `operatorfunc` is the best choice I guess.

Comment: Actually this works on a motion but I want it to work on text objects as well, so this isn't exactly what I'm looking for, although pretty close.

Comment: @user9397302 when you do `gsaip` the `ip` is a text object, and this works. Can you give an example of what you mean, that wouldn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok. I read *'Although "block" would rarely appear, since it can only result from Visual mode where "g@" is not useful.'* in the docs for `:map-operator` and thought it wouldn't work like that. Looks like this is one way to do it, though I ended up using the strategy described in this post -> http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Act_on_text_objects_with_custom_functions

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your `.vimrc` file :

```sh
vnoremap <silent> gsa :call Brackets()<CR>

function! Brackets()
    execute "normal! I'"
    if line(".") == a:lastline
        execute "normal! A'\<cr>]"
        execute a:firstline."s:^:[\r:" 
    else
        execute "normal! A',"
    endif
endfunction
```

Select the visual-line block you want for example `vip` and then press `gsa`.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, you seem to want to apply the *mapping* to each of the lines covered by a motion or text object.

You can establish such *range* via *visual mode*: `vip` or `v2j`. Then, you can use `:normal gsa` (typed; Vim automatically inserts the selected range (`:'<,'>`) if you enter command-line mode from visual mode) to apply your custom mapping to each of the lines (the cursor is positioned on the first column for each line, as per `:help :normal-range`).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add a comma after the last item, I would have done it this way, in order to leave registers unaltered.

```
function! s:to_list() range abort
  let words = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
  exe a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'d _' " remove the "_" to fill the unnamed register
  let lines = ['['] + map(words, '"  ".string(v:val).","') + [']']
  call append(a:firstline-1, lines)
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 -range=% ToList <line1>,<line2>call s:to_list()
```

In order to get rid of the last two lines, I've edited the last item of `map()` result or played with `join()`:

```
  let lines = "[\n" . join(map(words, '"  ".string(v:val)'), ",\n") . "\n]"
  put!=lines
```